# How to center a fixed element?

Tags: html, css

I'm a total novice in HTML/CSS, but I'm having trouble with centering a fixed h1 element. It refuses to center itself and sticks to the left side of the page. I've tried setting the margin to auto, but it doesn't do a thing. Here's the code:

```
h1 {
color: #580101;
font-family: RobotoRegular;
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
}

* {
 background-color: #ecebe9;
 }

#navbar {
color: #000653;
background-color: #00001a;
height: 40px;
border-radius: 3px;
}

.sidebar {
background-color: black;
width: 90px;
height: 500px;
float: left;
margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="Fonts/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="navbar"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

So, what should I do?

Comment: r u trying to get the h1 to be next to the div.sidebar? the h1 will be below thetwo above divs currently...?

Comment: no comments on the down votes?!?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use fixed position then add `width: 100%;` css rule for `h1` css style.

other just remove `position` that will work.

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/asivom/1/)**

Change **`<h1>`** `position:fixed` to `position:relative`

Answer (score 1):

the reason its sticking to the side of the page is because hence the name its fixed for example. you cannot tell it to freely float in the center if you have 'basically' demanded the element to be fixed, if that makes sense

you could do this

```
<style>
.test{
   position:fixed; 
   right:0; 
   left:0; 
   text-align:center; 
   background:#EEEEEE;
</style>
<h1 class="test">test</h1>
```

Answer (score -1):

When using `position`, specify it's position...`left`, `top`, or `right`, `bottom`.

Comment: How would you do that? Give an example.