# How to center an html component?

Tags: html, css

we would like to center an html component.

***The situation now:***

[image]

```css
.card{
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #54722b; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.card-header{
    background-color: rgb(221, 211, 123); 
}
.card-header h3{
     color: white;   
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form (ngSubmit)="register()">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name1" class="form-control">  
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name6" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***We tried: (but it didn't work)***

To add to the `.card` in the css file, the line:

```
position: fixed;
```

This line of code centered the component, but when we zoomed in, it was not possible to scroll the screen and see the entire component.

**How to center the html component, so that after zooming in, it will be possible to scroll the screen?**

Comment: It does works in the snippet..

Comment: It's possible that it's centered within its container but the container isn't the full width of the viewport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center a fixed element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037826/how-to-center-a-fixed-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can try these codes.

See to big screen: https://codepen.io/en0ndev/pen/bGgqpPm

```css
body {
  height:5000px;
}

.card_main {
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}

.card{
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #54722b; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.card-header{
    background-color: rgb(221, 211, 123); 
}
.card-header h3{
     color: white;   
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="card_main">

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form (ngSubmit)="register()">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name1" class="form-control">  
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name6" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it, but when I zoom in, I can't scroll the screen. Other idea? @en0ndev

Comment: How did you zoom in?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card{
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #54722b; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.card-header{
    background-color: rgb(221, 211, 123); 
}
.card-header h3{
     color: white;   
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form (ngSubmit)="register()">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name1" class="form-control">  
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name6" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center; 
}

.card{
    width: 400px;
    border: 3px solid #54722b; 
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.card-header{
    background-color: rgb(221, 211, 123); 
}
.card-header h3{
     color: white;   
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form (ngSubmit)="register()">
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name1" class="form-control">  
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name2" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name3" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name4" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input name="name5" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group">
                    <input  name="name6" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FlexBox styling:

`display: flex` property.
Once the container is `flex` container you can align the content centrally using

`align-content: center`  // along the cross axis, other possible values flex-start, flex-end

`justify-content: center`  //along the main axis

```
.card {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be on the parent container of .card.  You have a margin of auto, which should center the div inside the parent div.  Check the margins with inspector to see which container is causing the issue.

Answer (score -5):

Add margin:0 auto to css for .card
Or use center tags